# Laravel 8 Using Belongs To Failing When Using Where

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, belongs-to

I know this is me being dumb and not understanding the documentation but I am trying to use the `belongsTo` feature to access the parent of a class

In the model I have the function defined

```
class Child extends Model {

    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['childField'];

    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class, 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

But I am getting an error when trying to retrieve it in a controller

```
$child = Child::where('childField', 'ChildTest01')->get();
$parent = $child->parent->parentField;
```

The where is working because it's returning the right child but I'm getting an error saying that `Property [parent] does not exist` when trying to get the parent, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `$child` is a `Collection`, not a `Model`. It should be:

```php
$child = Child::where('childField', 'ChildTest01')->first();
$parent = $child->parent->parentField;
```

Comment: That did fix it, I'm not entirely sure why `get()` didn't work though but thank you so much!

Comment: `get()` returns a collection of models (even if the collection has only one item). `first()` returns the first model. You can only access the relationship from a model.

Comment: Oh wow ok that explains it, thanks a bunch!